# JPA shared-cache-mode CMS login not working

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, wildfly-8

I wrote a simple EAR application with a CMS login. When I have `<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>` the login is working perfectly, but if I use `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` I get the following exception:

```
Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required
    at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:284) [picketbox-4.0.21.Final.jar:4.0.21.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
...
```

I am totally sure that I use the right credentials. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: can you show more of the exception stack, and the persistence unit setup?

Comment: I solved the problem with a workaround. i packeged everything in a single wen application. now it is working perfectly. anyway an idea?